# How to implement LIKE functionality in a grouped query that depends on an IN operator?

Tags: mysql, sql

After some great interaction here in Stack Overflow I am able to implement queries to get all dishes that include ingredients A and B and those that are composed of ONLY ingredients A and B.

```
SELECT d.id, d.name 
FROM dishes d
JOIN dishes_ingredients di ON d.id = di.dishes_id
JOIN ingredients i ON di.ingredients_id = i.id
GROUP BY d.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN i.name IN ('apple', 'pear') THEN i.name END) = 2
AND COUNT(DISTINCT i.name) = 2  //--- for exclusivity
```

Now, when users search for `apple` and `pear`, they should also find a dish called "fruit wonder" that contains `Fuji apples` and `pear jam`. Dishes containing ingredients such as `green apple`, `red apple`, `apple jam`, `pear flavor`, etc, should also be found. If I use the above query and search for `apple` and `pear` I will not find the "fruit wonder" dish.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
HAVING SUM(i.name LIKE '%apple%') > 0 AND
       SUM(i.name LIKE '%pear%') > 0
```

You might also want:

```
SUM( i.name NOT LIKE '%apple%' AND i.name NOT LIKE '%pear%') = 0
```

If you want only apples and pears.

Comment: Thanks again. It works great. I just wanted to mention, that I added _AND COUNT(DISTINCT i.name) = 2_ at the end to avoid getting dishes that only have one apple ingredient, when the user searches for, say, 'apple' and 'apple jam'.

Comment: That also keeps the query from showing dishes that contain, say, 'apple', 'apple jam' and 'red apple', when the user searches for 'apple' and 'apple jam'...